# What does the notation $\times_K \mathscr{X}_k$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I need help understanding the second half of this equation. Specifically the $\times_K \mathscr{X}_k$ term. I believe the left hand side means that we have a set of n feature vectors each of which has k features. But, what is $\times_K$? Is $\mathscr{X}_k$ the $k$-th element of the set of all feature vectors?
$$\mathbf{x}^n = (x^n_1, x^n_2, \dotsc, x^n_K) \in \times_K \mathscr{X}_k.$$

I am still a student so, simple answers would be best.
I have checked the wiki table of math symbols as well as an online source for understanding set theory. But I do not understand the notation $\times_K \mathscr{X}_k$.

EDIT: To provide more information, this is from a research paper in computer science called "Timely Classification with Randomly Delayes Features" By Jie Xu

The full paragraph is:
We consider that a set of  classification tasks arrive in
sequence, indexed by {1,2,...,}. The -th task to arrive
is denoted by task . For each task , there is a cor-
responding data instance characterized by a feature vector
$^ = (^_1, ^_2, ..., ^_) ∈ ×_ _ ≜ .$ There is a label $^ ∈ $
associated with the instance $^$ but it is not revealed until
the classification is made. In the classical setting, a prediction
function  : $×_ _$ →  is used, taking the whole feature
vector $^$ as the input, to output a predicted label ˜$ ^$ . This
implicitly assumes that all features $^
_$ ,∀ become available
simultaneously so that the classifier can utilize all features. In
our considered setting, the different features of $^$ may not
arrive at the same time. Instead, features arrive in sequence
and let $^_$
denote the random delay associated with receiving
the feature  
 , which may be different for different tasks .
Hence, in order to know the value of  
 , we need to wait a
time of  
 . Denote by ( 1 ,...,  ) the joint distribution of
the random delays.

Comment: The notation used is not completely standard, but it should mean the Cartesian product $\mathscr{X}_1\times\mathscr{X}_2\times\cdots\times\mathscr{X}_K$. When we have have an (associative) operation $\star$, such as the cartesian product of sets, we sometimes denote the $k$-fold operation by $\star_{i=1}^k$, that is, $\star_{i=1}^k p_i=p_1\star p_2\star\cdots\star p_k$. This is also common for unions of sets: $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i=A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$.

Comment: @Luiz Thanks for the quick response. I think I understand.

Comment: As @LuizCordeiro suggests, this is probably the Cartesian product.  I think that a large Pi notation is more common:  $$\prod_{i=k}^{K} \mathscr{X}_{k}. $$  Unfortunately, I don't think that we have enough information to provide a more definitive answer---can you let us know where you are seeing this notation?

Comment: @Xander I added the full context in which its used to the post.